# Server Architecture for Subversion, TeamCity and Development Servers

Tags: .net, svn, teamcity

I work for a newer .Net CMS web development company and we are just now getting together a versioning strategy. We are currently leaning heavily toward subversion as the versioning system with TeamCity to keep our dev server updated (and control our builds to QA and production).

I am trying to find what type of architecture is suggested for such a set up. Should we have separate servers for each? What about TeamCity Server and the build agent(s)? It seems to me that the best way to go would be to set up one server to run subversion, one to run TeamCity Server and yet another to run the TeamCity Build Agent(s). However, we would like to avoid running three separate servers for this, of possible.

Can anyone tell me what they have used before and what works well? What do you suggest and why?

**UPDATE:** We would need to support about 10 developers. We're a little under that right now, but expect to hire a couple/few within the next year.

**UPDATE:** One more question. It seems by reading the documentation that we most likely wouldn't need more than the three Build Agents that go along with the Professional Services license, based on the number of developers we employ. It seems that this would need to increase if we had many more developers, but not necessarily by the number of active projects. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

- one server that hosts TeamCity and acts as a build agent
- one server for sql server storage. The TeamCity database is not the only database on there.
- two more servers for the two additional build agents.

We build a number of projects for multiple teams.

Initially there were only a handful of developers on one team. We were fine with one server acting as TeamCity server, TeamCity agent and database server.

You don't need multiple agents unless you want to build multiple projects at once, or you have a very long running build. We have found that the number of developers is not a direct factor.The number of concurrently running builds is more important. That could be related to the number of developers but it isn't in our case. We have a short build time (3 minutes) and we limit to one build per project at a time.

Comment: Thank you. How intensive is it on the database? We have a SQL Server we run our web services from, but our boss is leery of adding versioning work to it as well. Can it use a database other than SQL Server?

Comment: @unclesol It isn't intense, but that will vary with the number of builds running at once. Currently Sql Server, Oracle, Sybase, My Sql and PostgreSql are supported.

Comment: So, I could ostensibly run a copy of MySql and not touch my SQL Server. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your team. My company has 12 developers.

- We have a TeamCity web server that is also a build agent.
- The TeamCity database is on another SQL Server that we already had.
- Subversion is on another server that we already had.
- We used two developer machines as the second and third build agents.

But for a small team, you could probably put them all on one fairly powerful server. You'll have to see what works for you.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I've updated above to add some information, which, based upon your response, seemed useful.